# Javascript - get attribute of dropbox menu

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have this HTML code:

```
<select id="ITAAServerList" name="ITAAServerList" style="visibility:visible">
     <option ServerName="SERVER01" IPAddress="192.168.46.1" StartPageName="SERVER01_Start.html">SERVER01</option>
     <option ServerName="SERVER02" IPAddress="192.168.46.2" StartPageName="SERVER02_Start.html">SERVER02</option>
     <option ServerName="SERVER03" IPAddress="192.168.46.3" StartPageName="SERVER03_Start.html">SERVER02</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" name="oNext" id="oNext" onclick ="OnClickNext()" class="item cursor-pointer login-button">LOGIN</button>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="onclicknext.js"></script>
```

And this JS code:

```
function OnClickNext() {
    var oITAAServer = document.getElementById('ITAAServerList').options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('StartPageName');  
    alert(oITAAServer);
};
```

I can't get **StartPageName** attribute from the dropdown menu. Help?

Comment: Just updated JS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there - you just need to do `.selectedIndex` against the `<select>` element instead of against `this`.

```js
function OnClickNext() {
    var selectElement = document.getElementById('ITAAServerList');    
    var selectedOption = selectElement.options[ selectElement.selectedIndex ];  //not this.selectedIndex   
    var oITAAServer = selectedOption.getAttribute('StartPageName');  
    alert(oITAAServer);
};
```

```html
<select id="ITAAServerList" name="ITAAServerList" style="visibility:visible">
     <option ServerName="SERVER01" IPAddress="192.168.46.1" StartPageName="SERVER01_Start.html">SERVER01</option>
     <option ServerName="SERVER02" IPAddress="192.168.46.2" StartPageName="SERVER02_Start.html">SERVER02</option>
     <option ServerName="SERVER03" IPAddress="192.168.46.3" StartPageName="SERVER03_Start.html">SERVER03</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" name="oNext" id="oNext" onclick ="OnClickNext()" class="item cursor-pointer login-button">LOGIN</button>
```

Comment: That will do it, but I recommend avoiding really long lines that do lots of things - makes the code harder to maintain and manage.

Comment: Sorry, I am too new here :) I deleted the long code:

`var oITAAServer =document.getElementById('ITAAServerList').options[document.getElementById('ITAAServerList').selectedIndex].getAttribute('StartPageName');`

Will use yours instead!
This is just for reference for other people.